# In SSIS, why input for merge/merge join need to be sorted?

Tags: ssis, merge, transformation

I have been asked in interview why data need to be sorted for merge and merge join transformation? I know we can use merge and merge join without sort transformation by sorting the data at source and setting some properties. But still data has to be sorted, please tell me why it's mandatory?

Comment: The merge join algorithm requires the data to be sorted. It's an assumption the algorithm makes, and it makes it a very efficient algorithm, Alternatively the nested loops join algorithm does _not_ require data to be sorted. Read up on how merge join and nested loop algorithms work and you might understand better. To put it another way, you can use a nested loops join _or_ a merge join on sorted data but a merge join would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

It greatly speeds up matching.  If you imaging two stacks of cards that are incomplete decks and you want to find the common cards among them.

First try shuffling the decks, place them side by side, face up.  Say on the left you get the ten of spades, now search the deck on the right hand side for the ten of spades.  Since it is not ordered you may have to look at every card to find the ten of spades on the end of that deck.

Now sort those decks by suit and value and try the same excercize and you should now understand how sorting helps.  The process of sorting takes time and resources but much less than matching sorted lists and the difference grows exponentially as the number of records (cards) increases into the millions.